# Express-Fileupload not parsing files in heroku

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, file-upload, body-parser

I am using `express-fileupload` to parse the body of my request and access any files that are sent with the request. This works fine when I am trying to do this locally but when I push it to heroku, the files are not being parsed - instead `req.files` is `null`. My code is below:

Parsing middleware:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(fileUpload());  // EXPRESS-FILEUPLOAD BEING USED HERE
};
```

Routes file:

```
router.post('/photo', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("INSIDE OF THE ROUTE =======>>>>>");
    const userId = req.body.userId;
    const busketName = 'my-bucket-name';
    let newPhotosArray = [];
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    req.pipe(busboy);

    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        const filesObj = req.files;
        console.log('FILES OBJ: ', filesObj);  // THIS IS LOGGED OUT AS NULL ON HEROKU - LOCALLY IT IS AN OBJECT WITH FILES

        // rest of code....
    });
});
```

The code works great when I use it locally.  However, when I push the code to Heroku, req.files is null.  Why is this?

Comment: What's the purpose of using `busboy` here? `req.files` should be immediately populated with uploaded files without the need for busboy

Comment: you're right, that is unnecessary, but that does not address my issue.  Do you have any advice on that?

Comment: I'll need more information. What version of node are you using locally? What version of node are you using on Heroku? Is there a load balancer or some other router on Heroku that's serving your node server out?

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this?